# Chart.js disappears on page refresh

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Trying to use chart.js,but I am having an issue like chart will be displayed sometimes and it disappears on refreshing the page. I have also tried the solution given by Max on(Nov 7,14) to a similar issue, but unfortunately it is not working. Any suggestions?
 The code which i have tried:

```
 $(function(){


        var randomScalingFactor = $.getJSON('data.php',function(results)
        {
        var lineChartData = {
            labels: results[0],

            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)", 
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : results[1]
                }]

        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var chart =new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData,{
    responsive: true
    });
  });
});
```

Previously I used:

```
window.onload=function(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        var chart =new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData,{
        responsive: true
        });
```

Then as per the suggestion mentioned in this link:[Chart.js only appears randomly, and disappears on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806290/chart-js-only-appears-randomly-and-disappears-on-page-refresh), i changed my code which i have already posted. Even then it did not work.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? Specially when the chart isn't displayed.

Comment: Yes. There are no errors.

Comment: seeing as you draw the chart depending on a successful ajax call I would bet the issue lies with the response from `data.php`. What does it say in your network tab for that call when it does not disaply

Comment: I got it solved. You are right @Quince. The issue was with the response from data.php. Thank You.